# Extracting month and day from date using Perl

Tags: perl, date

I have a data file that has Dates listed. The dates are in the format as m/d/yyyy. An example is shown below:

```
1/1/2011
1/10/2011
10/1/2011
10/10/2011
```

My question is, how can I extract the month and day, so I can store it in a different file in two seperate columns? For example, I would like to show as

```
Month  Day
1       1
1       10
10      1
10      10
```

Comment: You should be able to easily do this using `split`.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 1):

`my ($Day, $Month, $Year) = split(m{/}, $Line);`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your dates follow the same format, then you don't even need a regex. The general form of the solution is as follows:

```
my ($month, $day, $year) = split(m@/@, $date);
```

If you're reading from a file `dates.txt`, you might use it thus:

```
open my $DATES, '<', 'dates.txt'
  or die "Couldn't open dates.txt: $!\n";

while (my $date = <$DATES>) {
  $date =~ s@\r|\n@@g; # get rid of trailing newlines, however formatted
  my ($month, $day, $year) = split(m@/@, $date);
  # whatever you need to do with the date parts, do here
};

close DATES;
```

Be advised that, per your educational institution's academic honor policy, you may be required to cite this Stack Overflow answer as a reference when you turn in your homework, on pain of various penalties up to and potentially including expulsion.

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl`

```
perl -pe 's#(\d+)/(\d+)/\d+#$1\t$2#' file > new_file
```

Using `sed`

```
sed -r 's#([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/[0-9]+#\1\t\2#' file > new_file
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, rather than using `split`, is is clearest to extract all numeric fields from the string using a regular expression

```
my ($m, $d, $y) = $date =~ /\d+/g;
```

Here is a complete program showing the idea.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @dates = qw<
  1/1/2011
  1/10/2011
  10/1/2011
  10/10/2011
>;

print "Month  Day\n";

for (@dates) {
  my ($m, $d, $y) = /\d+/g;
  printf "%-7d %-7d\n", $m, $d;
}
```

**output**

```
Month  Day
1       1      
1       10     
10      1      
10      10
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `split` with a slice:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

for my $date (qw(1/1/2011
                 1/10/2011
                 10/1/2011
                 10/10/2011)) {
    say join "\t", (split m{/}, $date)[0, 1];
}
```

Comment: `use strict` and implicit `$_`? Interesting combination.

Comment: @AaronMiller: OK, added a name.